# CGRectの上手な書き方

Tags: swift

Swiftにおいて、CGRectを変更する場合は

```
let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:100.0, width:200.0, height:200.0)
//widthを変更したい
view.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:100.0, width:300.0, height:200.0)
```

と、このようにwidthだけ変更したい場合でもCGRectの長い文をツラツラ書いています。

このようにCGRectを一箇所だけ変更したい場合において、何か上手な書き方ってありますか？

また、どういったメリット、デメリットがあって

```
view.frame.width = 300.0
```

という書き方ができないように、CGRectのプロパティがreadonlyにしてあるのかも
教えていただけると参考になります。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGRect`という構造体に対する誤解があるように見えます。構造体`CGRect`はそもそもなにかを調べることから始めましょう。
Xcodeの索引能力は強力です。それを使わない手はありません。Xcodeのエディタに`CGRect`と入力します。その上にマウスカーソルを当て、Optionキーを押しながらクリックすると、ミニリファレンスが現れます。（下図）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ミニリファレンスの一番下の行「Reference」をクリックすると、フルリファレンスが開きます。そこには、`CGRect`の定義が書かれています。

```
struct CGRect {
    var origin: CGPoint
    var size: CGSize

    init()
    init(origin origin: CGPoint, size size: CGSize)
}
```

`CGRect`は、`CGPoint`と`CGSize`をメンバーとする構造体であることがわかります。
質問者さんの予想と違っていたのではありませんか？質問者さんは、このように予想していらっしゃったのでは？

```
struct CGRect {
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    var width: CGFloat
    var height: CGFloat
}
```

予想どおりなら、`view.frame.width = 300.0`という書き方ができるはずですが、予想どおりではないので、そうは書けません。`width`は`CGRect`のメンバーではないんですね。けっして、`CGRect`のプロパティ（メンバー）がRead Onlyだからではありません。
`width`は`CGSize`のメンバーです。

```
view.frame.size.width = 300.0
```

これなら書けます。
「いちいち`size`を書くのはめんどう」と思われるかもしれません。その場合は、`CGRect`を拡張してあげましょう。

```
extension CGRect {
    var width: CGFloat {
        get {
            return self.size.width
        }
        set {
            self.size.width = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

こう拡張すると、`view.frame.width = 300.0`が可能になります。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！
最後のextension CGRect  ~~
という処理はどのファイルに記述すればよいでしょうか？
自分でファイルを作って書くとおもうのですが、まだクラスを継承してファイルを作成したことしかありませんでしたので、よろしければご教授ください。

Comment: どこに記述しても、プロジェクト全体で有効になります。ぎゃくに、記述したSwiftファイル内のみ有効にする場合、冒頭に`private`をつけます。

Answer (score 3):

> どういったメリット、デメリットがあって
>
> ```
> view.frame.width = 300.0
> ```
>
> という書き方ができないように、CGRectのプロパティがreadonlyにしてあるのか

の部分ですが、メリット・デメリットというよりはSwiftからFoundationのデータ型をimportする部分を設計した人のデザインセンスの問題ということになりそうです。

CGRectはObjective-C側で次のように宣言されています。

```
struct CGRect {
    CGPoint origin;
    CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

ご覧のようにCGRectにはwidthというプロパティ(Objective-Cのstructならメンバーというべきでしょうか)はありません。
　Objective-Cでは、structにプロパティやメソッドを追加することはできませんでしたから、CGRectのwidthにアクセスする場合には、素直にメンバー階層をたどるか、

```
CGRect rect = CGRectZero;
CGFloat width = rect.size.width;
```

あるいはアクセス関数を用いるしかありませんでした。

```
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(rect);
```

これらのアクセス関数にはいろいろあります(CGGetMinX()やらCGRectIsNull()やら...)が、Swiftでそれらのimport部分の設計を担当した人は、それらのアクセス関数をextension内でプロパティとしてもアクセスできるようにしてしまったようです。
(Cmd-Clickで表示されるヘッダにおけるCGRectのextension部分)

```
extension CGRect {
    //...
    public var width: CGFloat { get }
    //...
    public var minX: CGFloat { get }
    //...
    public var isNull: Bool { get }
    //...
}
```

実際[オープンソース化されたSwiftのソース](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.swift)を見るとそれらのプロパティは次のような感じで定義されています。

```
  var width:  CGFloat {
    @_transparent // @fragile
    get { return CGRectGetWidth(self) }
  }
  //...
  var minX:   CGFloat {
    @_transparent // @fragile
    get { return CGRectGetMinX(self) }
  }
```

(`@_transparent`とかはライブラリの作者が内部的に使うものなので無視してください。)
したがって、「CGRectのwidthプロパティは、あくまでもCGRectGetWidth()を呼ぶためのショートカットである」と言うふうに理解すべきなのでしょう。(CGRectSetWidth()なんて関数はなかったので、setterは存在しない。)
　ただ、widthやheightなど、矛盾なくsetterを定義できるものについて、あえてそうはしなかったのは、「設計者のデザインセンス」としか言えないように思います。

Comment: 二つ目の疑問にお答えいただきありがとうございます。
swiftやObjective-Cの宣言は見てはいたのですが、
それがどういうことなのか、まだ理解できていなかったようです。
設計者のデザインセンスであったということは、先の回答にありましたように、view.frame.width=300.0 というような書き方できるように自分で実装しても問題ないということですね。

Comment: 「問題ない」をどのレベルまで考えるか微妙ですが、言語処理系の実装に関わる技術的な部分から言うと、すでにextensionで定義されているプロパティを自前のextensionで上書きしてしまってもいいかどうか、この辺りSwiftの動作はまだ十分仕様化されておらず、若干不安は残ります。(私が知らないだけの可能性もありますが。)

Answer (score 2):

```
let view = UIView()    
view.frame.size.width = 300.0
```

のように書くのはどうでしょうか？